Is it possible to change a value passed by reference within a coroutine?
I'm essentially trying to make a working version of this:
public static Coroutine AnimateValue(this MonoBehaviour behaviour, ref float value, float endValue)
{
    return behaviour.StartCoroutine(AnimationCoroutine(ref value, endValue));
}

private static IEnumerator AnimationCoroutine(ref float value, float endValue)
{
    float timeElapsed = 0f;
    float startValue = value;

    while (timeElapsed < 1)
    {
        value = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed);
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    value = endValue
}

This is a simplified version of my code that outlines the issue I'm having. I'm trying to make a convenient method that automatically starts a coroutine to animate a value from its current state to a given state. To do this, I have a static method that takes a reference to a float as a parameter. I want to then call a coroutine that updates this value.
Firstly, the example I've just given doesn't work because IEnumerators can't take ref parameters.
Next, I tried using delegates.
public delegate void UpdateValueDelegate(float newValue);

public static Coroutine AnimateValue(this MonoBehaviour behaviour, ref float value, float endValue)
{
    UpdateValueDelegate onUpdate = (newValue) => value = newValue;
    return behaviour.StartCoroutine(AnimationCoroutine(onUpdate, startValue, endValue));
}

private static IEnumerator AnimationCoroutine(UpdateValueDelegate onUpdate, float startValue, float endValue)
{
    float timeElapsed = 0f;

    while (timeElapsed < 1)
    {
        onUpdate(Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed));
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    onUpdate(endValue);
}

This also doesn't work because you can't use ref inside of a lambda.
I've tried storing the ref as a variable.
private ref float currentValue;

But "Feature 'ref fields' is not available in C# 9.0. Please use language version 11.0 or greater.". As far as I'm aware, Unity doesn't support version C# 11.0.
The only thing I've found that has worked is passing a delegate as a parameter when calling the method.
public static Coroutine AnimateValue(this MonoBehaviour behaviour, ref float value, float endValue, UpdateValueDelegate onUpdate)
{
    return behaviour.StartCoroutine(AnimationValue(onUpdate, value, endValue));
}

this.AnimateValue(ref value, 5, (newValue) => value = newValue);

But I want to make this method as quick and easy-to-use as possible and and having to define a lambda like this every time makes it a lot more cumbersome and annoying. I don't want to add any extra parameters to the AnimateValue method if possible, thus my original question.

Wow, this is such a badly designed code. No wonder you are having problems.
Why do you need to return enumerator? Why do you have to use ref values?

If you could explain why it's badly designed I'd appreciate it.
The IEnumerator is run over a period of time and returning it allows me to use StopCoroutine if I want to stop the animation midway through; can't do that if I don't have a reference to it.
As for why ref values, it just seemed like the easiest way to go? I'll admit that I haven't really used them before but it feels like a better solution than using the exact same lambda with a swapped out variable every time.

I realise most of the issues with design come from Unity itself. I would use a while (timeElapsed < 1) loop as a main loop and get and set the values inside, while advancing frames manually (if that's possible). Can't really refactor this without knowing if advancing frames manually possible and without seeing where original value comes from and how it is used after being modified

Also, the simplest solution I can see if you want to keep everything the same would be to try to use a struct or class instead of ref value.

@Tanuki if you don't know the framework maybe you shouldn't answer/comment on Unity specific questions then? ;) And no you can not really advance frames in the engine core manually. OP: what exactly is the final goal? I don't really see what speaks against using some sort of callback (lambda or not)

I'm trying to make a generalised method I can call from any MonoBehaviour to animate a float from its current value to a given one. I'm aware that I can use the lamba (newValue) => value = newValue) as a callback, where value is the float on the MonoBehaviour I'm trying to change. The thing is, I'll have to use that exact same lamba every single time I call the method, swapping out the float with the one I'm trying to change. It physcially works, but it would be much nicer if I could just reference the float itself. I just want to make calling the method as simple as possible.

@derHugo Yep, my bad. I commented first before realising it is in Unity. However, I would love to see the correct solution from the Unity expert such as yourself

As @Tanuki already mentioned the simplest solution would be to just pass in a wrapper class instead public class FloatValue { public float Value; } .. that's a reference type so you can just pass it in as parameter ... still though: I would really rather go with an event driven / callback based solution tbh
